# Unit Tests Triangle

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have an interface

```
public interface Triangle {
int X1();
int Y1();
int X2();
int Y2();
int X3();
int Y3();}
```

that contains methods that return the 6 integers, which are the coordinates of the three vertices of a right triangle in the Cartesian coordinate system.
And i have a method that returns a right-angled triangle:

```
public final class RtriangleProvider {
public static Rtriangle getRtriangle() {
}
}
```

I should write the code one junit test method getRtriangle that he indeed returns a right-angled 
triangle.
Here is my UnitTest:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class RtriangleProviderTest{
@Test
public void Test(){

    Rtriangle test = RtriangleProvider.getRtriangle();
    assertNotNull("The input data are not available", test);
    double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((test.getX1()-test.getX2()),2)+(int)Math.pow((test.getY1()-test.getY2()),2));
    double b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((test.getX2()-test.getX3()),2)+(int)Math.pow((test.getY2()-test.getY3()),2));
    double c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((test.getX1()-test.getX3()),2)+(int)Math.pow((test.getY1()-test.getY3()),2));
    assertTrue ("The sum of two sides is less than the third, not the triangle",a < b + c && b < c + a && c < a + b);
    assertTrue("Not rectangle triangle in accordance with Pythagorian theorem",((int)Math.pow(a,2)==(int)Math.pow(b,2)+(int)Math.pow(c,2))||
            ((int)Math.pow(b,2) == (int)Math.pow(a,2)+(int)Math.pow(c,2))||
            ((int)Math.pow(c,2) == (int)Math.pow(b,2)+(int)Math.pow(b,2))
    );

}


}
```

I think, my test is not complete. Please, tell me what is wrong in my test

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might not be what you want to hear but I think all the calcs must be placed within the triangle object. So you would end up with something like:

```
public interface Triangle {
   int X1();
   int Y1();
   int X2();
   int Y2();
   int X3();
   int Y3();
   double a();
   double b();
   double c();
   boolean isTheSumOfSidesLessThanAThird();
   boolean isATriangleInAccordancePythagorianTheorem();     
}
```

After refactoring the triangle class, I would tidy up the asserts:

```
// Given...
Rtriangle test = RtriangleProvider.getRtriangle();

// When and Then...        
assertThat(test, isNotNullValue());
assertThat(test.isTheSumOfSidesLessThanAThird(), isTrue());
assertThat(test.isATriangleInAccordanceWithPythagorianTheorem(), isTrue());
```

I think the calcs to assert whether the sum of the sides is < than a 3rd and if the triangle is Pythagorian belong to the triangle itself so I would start off by moving these methods to the triangle class.

You should avoid keeping complex logic (such as these calcs) in the test itself because you may make a mistake when writing the test code and, depending on what mistake you made, the test will pass with flying colors though it asserts wrong values. There are situations where you cannot avoid writing complex logic in the test but you must do everything you can to avoid being caught in these situations.

I don't know how this *RTriangleProvider* class works but you should be able to mock its behaviour so that it sets known values for Xs and Ys and therefore you would know what to expect when calling *a()*, *b()*, *c()*, *isTheSumOfSidesLessThanAThird()* and *isATriangleInAccordanceWithPythagorianTheorem()*.

Keep in mind:

1. If you are going to mock the *RTriangleProvider*, you *might* need to make its factory method non-static.
2. If you cannot mock the behaviour of the *RTriangleProvider*, you may want to review its design and implementation because it's likely it has technical flaws.